# How to import an Access database to GeoDjango?

Tags: geodjango, export, ms-access

I'm a I've just inherited a pile of institutional geodata that's stored in an MS Access database.  I need to pull that data out into a format that I can work with in GeoDjango--so I'm OK with shapefiles or exporting it directly to a more useful database (mysql or postgres).  What's the best way to do that?  I'm a GIS newb, so I'm hoping there's an easy solution here.

I can get access to an ArcGIS install to work with the data if necessary.

Comment: Does the MS Access data contain the spatial information, or are these just attributes related to the spatial data?

Comment: @celenius The database contains spacial data--there is a long binary column in each table called "shape", I believe.

Comment: Do you know what software created the Access DB? If you open MS Access, are there a bunch of "GDB_" Tables? This likely means it is an ESRI Geodatabase. More than likely its ESRI, but Geomedia (and likely others) also use MS Access to store spatial data. If you find a GDB_ReleaseInfo table, open it and the "Minor" field should tell you which 9.x GDB version it is.  If GDB_ReleaseInfo is missing, it is likely a 10.x GDB.

Comment: @RyanDalton My understanding is that the data was generated in ArcGIS, and there are a bunch of GDB_* tables.  I don't see GDB_ReleaseInfo, but there is a GDB_Release table with one row (Major,Minor,Bugfix):(1,1,0).

Comment: It likely means then that it is an ESRI 8.1 geodatabase.  That should help others in suggesting appropriate solutions.

Answer (score 5):

You could probably migrate your data out of the Personal Geodatabase and directly into PostGIS using [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), which supports both [Personal Geodatabase and PostGIS](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html) file formats.

Answer (score 2):

I am about to play around with GeoKettle http://www.spatialytics.org/projects/geokettle/ this perfoms ETL on various datasets, the data I have is in CSV, so I would imagine that if Geokettle does not natively support Access you can dump it to csv.

Answer (score 2):

As Ryan Dalton said you can use OGR2OGR.
The FWTools binaries for windows seem to have ESRI Personal Geodatabase support built in. You can easily export data using the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=someuser dbname=somedb password=somepassword port=5432" C:\GISData\Geonames.mdb -a_srs EPSG:26986
```

**CREDITS**: the above information has been taken from [bostongis.com](http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet#41), scroll down to '*ESRI GeoDatabase (MDB format)*' for the relevant section.